# How to display enum description in response of API.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I have a enum like this,

[image]

I have created an IEnumerable of this enum type. And then I am calling API to fetch the list of this enum type, In response I got the values of enum, What I want is, the API response should contain the description of Enum.

How to achieve this in C#.

Comment: Why do you post text as image?

Comment: What type of server surfaces that in what format. Besides DescriptionAttribute is mostly for visual designers (especially the ones from Visual Studio) so presumably there isn't anything built in.